# why do i keep getting errors in my selection sort algorithm

Tags: java, sorting

so based on my lectures, book and what I found online my code is proper but I keep getting the same errors no matter what I do. it has become quite discouraging any help would be awesome.

```
public class OrderedArrayList extends UnorderedArrayList
{

public OrderedArrayList(int size)
{
      super(size);
}

public OrderedArrayList()
{
    super();
}

    //Copy constructor
public OrderedArrayList(OrderedArrayList otherList)
{
    super(otherList);
 }

public void sort()
{// start sort
int min;
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
{
    min = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++)
     {
        if (list[j] < list[min]) 
        {
            min = j;

        }
     }
    if (min != i)
     {
        final int temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[min];
        list[min] = temp;
     }
    System.out.println(list[i]);//  print in ascending order  
    }


 }// end sort

}
```

Here is the error:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g OrderedArrayList.java
  OrderedArrayList.java:29: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
        if (list[j] < list[min]) 
                    ^
  first type:  DataElement
 second type: DataElement
 OrderedArrayList.java:37: error: incompatible types: DataElement 
 cannot be converted to int
        final int temp = list[i];
                             ^
  OrderedArrayList.java:39: error: incompatible types: 
  int cannot be converted      to DataElement
        list[min] = temp;
                    ^
   3 errors
```

no matter what data type I write it for integer string I always get the same errors every time. this lab requires it to be DataElement.

Comment: I edited the post to add errors as code

Comment: What is `list`?

Comment: If you want to sort a custom class need to either sort on one int attribute of that class to fit your current code or implement `Comparable`. What is your `DataElement` class and what is it you are trying to sort on?

Comment: Hi @Chewy2387 & welcome to SO. To help us answer your question could you mention a few details? What is `UnorderedArrayList`? What's the type of `list`, and where is that defined? It looks as if `list[j]` does not contain the type of data you think it does, but it's hard for us to tell since we're missing those details.

Comment: Our professor gave us 4 classes and the lab is to create an inheritance of unorderedArrayList that will sort the list of any data type. All the data types in unorderedArrayList are also set as DataElement

Comment: there are our instructionsCreate and name the Class "OrderedArrayList" and make sure it extends UnorderedArrayList.   
You will want the same constructors as UnorderedArrayList (only these are for OrderedArrayList).
Place the method to sort the array in this Class.
Remember - the datatype here is DataElement!!  This means that this class will work for both integers AND strings.DO NOT add any other methods to this Class.  It should only contain the sort method. 
So when you swap elements in the array and need a temporary variable to store a value then that value will be of type DataElement!

Comment: You have the answer in your last comment , don’t use int use DateElement in your code

Answer (score 0):

Here is your sort method using DateElement instead of int.

```
public void sort() {// start sort
    int min;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
            if (list[j].compareTo(list[min]) < 0) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (min != I) {
            final DateElement temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[min];
            list[min] = temp;
        }
        System.out.println(list[i]);//  print in ascending order  
    }
}
```

Note that I haven’t checked the sorting itself, I just fixed the issue with DateElement

Comment: yes but the problem is my list becomes null when I call the sort method for some reason even though prior to calling sort it has data in it. the error occurs at the first if statement of the sort method

Comment: @StevenAnderson I am not sure how that is related to the errors you posted in your question or the code posted?

Comment: my apologies I have another post about this same code. I got it to compile but now my list turns up null when it is sent to the sort method, despite it not being null when working with it in the driver before sending it to sort.

Comment: @StevenAnderson Well that sounds like it's outside the scope of this question then, specially since it happens before the sort method is called.